# Jquery Not Applying on first visit

Tags: jquery, ajax

Good Afternoon All!

I must apologise i am very new to Jquery and have made this code by searching the internet trying to understand what it all means.

I have created this Jquery to replace some text on my site to appear with no text. This code does work however if you visit the page linked below you will see that the Jquery does not apply on the users first visit so the text is still visible. The "Sale" text will then disappear after refreshing the page.

As i mentioned i have build this code based on things i have looked up and thankfully managed to get to the stage i am at.

I saw the use of `('active')` however i am not sure what this does..

If someone could help point me in the right direction it would mean a lot
https://www.thekidswarehouse.co.uk/kids-lego

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>$(document).ready(function() {$('.product-mark').text(''); });</script>
```

What i have done is applied a background image to the sale icon on square space then attempted to hide the "Sale" text.

Regards,

Anthony

Comment: Worked first time for me. What makes you think it's not working? Have you checked your browser console for errors?

Comment: Hi Phil thanks for the reply. it is the white "sale" text i am referring to https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5c0056b889c172e3e1f0c651/t/5c9298dc085229b8f882e3a2/1553111265210/jquery.png circled in green

Comment: That text doesn't appear to be part of the markup. When I inspected the elements, they did not contain any text nodes

Comment: This is what i am modifying. https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5c0056b889c172e3e1f0c651/t/5c92bad5971a1824d79874e5/1553119960631/product-mark.png or trying to atleast

Comment: Never mind did it in CSS in the end..